# Is CFBundleIdentifier Localizable?

Tags: ios, localization, cfbundleidentifier

Can we localize `CFBundleIdentifier` , I am using `CFBundleIdentifier` as a key to store something in Plist , In case `CFBundleIdentifier` is localizable I would not be able to access the data stored in Plist, I have looked into apple doc, as per my understanding `CFBundleIdentifier` is not localizable, Please correct me If I am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the bundle identifier is not localizable. It's the unique ID of your app. It must remain constant.

Answer (score -1):

CFBundleIdentifier uniquely identifies the bundle. Each distinct app
     or bundle on the system must have a unique bundle ID. The system 
     uses this string to identify your app in many ways. For example, the
     preferences system uses this string to identify the app for which a 
     given preference applies; Launch Services uses the bundle identifier
     to locate an app capable of opening a particular file, using the
     first app it finds with the given identifier; in iOS, the bundle
     identifier is used in validating the app’s signature.

The bundle ID string must be a uniform type identifier (UTI) that
     contains only alphanumeric (A-Z,a-z,0-9), hyphen (-), and period (.)
     characters. The string should also be in reverse-DNS format. For 
     example, if your company’s domain is Ajax.com and you create an app
     named Hello, you could assign the string com.Ajax.Hello as your 
     app’s bundle identifier.